# Can I install php-ldap 5.3.3 when my php version is 5.4.31?

Tags: php, yum

I have php 5.4.31 installed on a Centos 6 machine.
When I use
yum install php-ldap

The information yum provides me after I run the command is in the picture.
[image]

So yum asks whether I want to install php-ldap version 5.3.3-49 and php-common version 5.3.3-49. Can I let yum install these suggested packages?

My server has php version  5.4.31 and I want to keep it like that for now.

Comment: Where did you get `php-5.4.31` for `Centos 6` ? It only supports up to `5.3.3-49` !

Comment: I have `php-5.6.34-1.el6.remi.x86_64` so suspect it may of come from Remi - I can see `php-ldap-5.4.45` listed in there as well.